# The meaning of the frequency value in rosbags

Tags: ros-melodic, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

i downloaded a rosbag from the internet and looked at the info of this file:

```
path:        ../raw/Vehicle1_velodyne_pos.bag
version:     2.0
duration:    36:10s (2170s)
start:       Aug 12 2015 09:22:18.17 (1439364138.17)
end:         Aug 12 2015 09:58:28.86 (1439366308.86)
size:        23.0 MB
messages:    152840
compression: none [29/29 chunks]
types:       tf/tfMessage [94810edda583a504dfda3829e70d7eec]
topics:      tf   152840 msgs @ 99.2 Hz : tf/tfMessage
```

As you can see, the topic **tf** have 152840 messages and after that there is the number 99.2 Hz.

I computed:

```
 (end_time - start_time) / number of messages
```

and i got ca. 70 Hz.

What is the meaning of the number 99.2 Hz?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/308392/the-meaning-of-the-frequency-value-in-rosbags/) by [quantum](https://answers.ros.org/users/38413/quantum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2018-11-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline#rosbag_info) this is the **median** frequency. Since it's a `median`, the topic have received/published the same amount of messages at a faster and at a slower rate than `99,2hz`. Your calculation is actually the `mean` rate of the topic. If the `mean = median` then you have a symetric distribution, here you have `mean < median` so it's a negatively skewed distribution.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2018-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kansai](https://answers.ros.org/users/54052/kansai/) on 2021-09-08**:
How come when I do the same (rosbag info) I got no frequency at all??  `topics:      /camera/image    1187 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Image`